# \leq symbol in hyperref text field

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, textfield

I would like to insert the "lesser or equal" symbol (\leq in latex) *inside* a TextField from the hypperref package. Is this possible ? And how ?

I get the error :
"Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref) removing `\leq' on input line 11."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

$\leq$ \\

\TextField[value= $\leq$]{} % how to input this symbol here ?

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert the unicode symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

%\TextField[name=box,value=^^^^2264]{} % luatex
\TextField[name=box,value=\000\040\042\144]{} % pdftex

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the value "fi" inside the form instead of the symbol. I'm actually using pdfLaTex. Does that changes anything ?

Comment: My screenshot is from a pdflatex compilation. Did you try exactly my example?

Comment: My bad, I looked at the wrong output.. Thanks a lot ! Would you have a link to find the different unicode values for different symbols for pdftex ?